# How to use passport.js github strategy to get emails of users instead of null

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js, github-oauth, passport-github2

I successfully got the user details but the email field is null.After some time got to know that I need to fetch it from "https://api.github.com/user/emails".I used axios and also provided accesstoken as header but it is giving me "▼♥��A�@►���\�%♥+=y��5"V↔ubWevW�迧F�¶◄t��☻�%)H�ɢ�k��♥葩$,�7↓�H�↔?��^Z�k�r���:��x�▬♣▬NP������҇�C�v�C▼o.�pK~☺" instead of emails.

```
passport.use(new GitHubStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "/callbackurl"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
  User.findOrCreate({ githubId: profile.id }, function (err, user){   //I am using mongoose-findorcreate npm
      axios.get('https://api.github.com/user/emails', {
 headers: {
   "Authorization": "Bearer "+ accessToken,
 }
}).then((res)=>{
  console.log(res.data);
})
      return done(err, user);
    });
  }
));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have not specified scope inside your strategy so Inside your github Strategy , also include scope key:
scope: ["user:email"],
As:

```
`new GitHubStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "/callbackurl",
    scope: ["user:email"]
}`
```